# How to automatically create the installation zip archive of a Joomla extension?

Tags: development, extensions, packaging

Is there any widespread, generally accepted way to automatically create the installation zip archive for extensions, or does each extension developer use his own hand made tools and recipes?

Does someone have any suggestion about what tool or script should use a developer that starts now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a (free) component called [JDeveloper](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jdeveloper). It's mainly for extension development, but it also has a function to create and download a zip-file from any existing Joomla extension. Just install the component, and go to **JDeveloper** -> **Extensions**, select your extension and click "Create ZIP" in the upper left corner.

**Note that this does not seem to include files from the `/media/` folder.**

[image: JDeveloper create ZIP]

Comment: JDeveloper is an extremely simple product, suitable for simple projects. This is its strength and its limit. For a more powerful and customizable tool, read the Lodder's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

I personally keep my extensions (modules only) on Github using the same directory tree as you'd find with any other extension.

So when I make changes to a file on my localhost, I copy the file over to the cloned repository.

When I'm ready to release an update or new extension even, I simply zip up all the files/directories in the cloned repository.

This would not be a good approach for components as they're much bigger. For this, I'd suggest using [Phing](https://docs.joomla.org/Extension_development_using_eclipse_and_phing). Not only will it allow you to create zips, it it makes a lot of other things automated.

Comment: Thanks for your exhaustive reply. I've tried both, Phing and JDeveloper. While in my particular case Phing is more suitable, I thought that johanpw's answer meets best the needs of beginners, as I asked for. It's a pity that I can't accept both the answers :(

Comment: So, may I ask you a bit more detailed: You use git. Are you working in the folders of joomla directly (on the localhost installation) or outside and pushing/installing in regular intervals to debug/test? If inside joomla: What are you putting under source control? Only the relevant folder in the joomla installation (i.e. the folder modules/mod_foo of the module foo) or more? Thank you for clarification.